# VB.NET Refresh other DataGridView based if changing in another DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I habe a `DataGridView` which shows the attributes of employees. I can add remove, save, everything works quite fine.
In the same form I have another `DataGridView` which shows to which employeegroups the employees belong. The datamodel is like this:
tableEmployees.PK --> table Employeegroups FK
Employeenr --> Employeenr

Now I tried several ways (it feels like hundreds) to refresh the second DataGridView. 
Because I wanted a possibility to test a bit easier the code is now in an buttonevent I will change it, if it works.

Here are my datacollections:

```
 T_MAGruppenTableAdapter.Fill(dtMAGruppen)
 TMAGruppenBindingSource.DataSource = dtMAGruppen
```

Out of the names you can see the types.

Here is how I fill my DataGridView:

```
 Private Sub DataGridMAGruppen_Fill()
    ' Set up the DataGridView.

    Dim Mitarbeiternr, Gruppennr As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

    With Me.DataGridMAGruppen
        .AutoGenerateColumns = False
        .DataSource = db.TMAGruppenBindingSource
        .AutoSizeRowsMode = _
            DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
    End With
    With Me.DataGridMAGruppen.Columns

        With Mitarbeiternr
            .DataPropertyName = "Mitarbeiternr"
            .DataSource = db.TMitarbeiter2BindingSource
            .DisplayMember = "NN"
            .ValueMember = "nr"
            .FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat
            .HeaderText = "Mitarbeiter"
            .Width = 193
        End With
        With Gruppennr
            .DataPropertyName = "Gruppennr"
            .DataSource = db.TGruppenBindingSource
            .DisplayMember = "Gruppename"
            .ValueMember = "nr"
            .FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat
            .HeaderText = "Gruppe"
            .Width = 190
        End With
        .AddRange(Mitarbeiternr, Gruppennr)
    End With

End Sub
```

And here are my tries to refresh this DataGridView:

```
    db.TableAdapterSpeichern(1)
    db.TMAGruppenBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
    'db.dtMAGruppen.Clear()
    'db.T_MAGruppenTableAdapter.Fill(db.dtMAGruppen)
    'DataGridMAGruppen.DataSource = db.dtMAGruppen
```

The dataadapters etc. have a prefix because I made a database class.

So how can I easily refresh the DataGridview MaGruppen after update the DataGridViewEmployees?

*EDIT ADD Method tableAdapterSpeichern

```
   Public Sub TableAdapterSpeichern(ByVal Typ As Integer)

    Dim test As Integer

    Select Case Typ
        Case 1      'Person

            TMitarbeiterBindingSource.EndEdit()
            test = T_MitarbeiterTableAdapter.Update(CType(TMitarbeiterBindingSource.DataSource, DataTable))
        Case 2      'KFZ
            TKFZBindingSource.EndEdit()
            T_KFZTableAdapter.Update(CType(TKFZBindingSource.DataSource, DataTable))
        Case 3  'Gruppen
            TMAGruppenBindingSource.EndEdit()
            T_MAGruppenTableAdapter.Update(CType(TMAGruppenBindingSource.DataSource, DataTable))
        Case 4      'Person
            TMitarbeiter1BindingSource.EndEdit()
            T_Mitarbeiter1TableAdapter.Update(CType(TMitarbeiter1BindingSource.DataSource, DataTable))
    End Select

End Sub
```

I can add new employees and everything, it should work, the type I use to save the employees is 1.

Comment: Why not just call the `DataGridMAGruppen_Fill()` subroutine again after updating the other one..?

Comment: Because, it doesn't work which I don't understand

Comment: Show the code that you're trying to do this (The save function)

Comment: I just did add TableAdapterSpeichern()